# Chess client for e-(g)mail

Tags: chess, online

I'm looking for something that would let me store the board setup and move the pieces manually so that I can play with a friend via email/msn. It doesn't have to handle mailing or anything for me as long as I can move the pieces around :)

Comment: Your title is deceptive, if it doesn't have to handle e-mail, aren't you just looking for a web-client?

Comment: Well preferably it'll handle it by email obviously but as a second hand choice I'm fine with anything that can just remember the layout of the chess board. The game either way will be played via email regardless of weather we are sending move or the "client" handles it for us. End of the day the app/client/webpage I want to find is a helper for chess games via email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### GamesByMail

[Scott Michtell](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/44/scott-mitchell) just introduced me to [GamesByMail](http://gamesbyemail.com/) to play Axis & Allies, and I noticed that it has chess as well.

All you need is an e-mail address to create a small profile, same thing for your opponent, and you're ready to play.  You should get e-mail reminders when it is your turn.

I haven't tried chess there yet, but if it's anything like A&A was, you should be in good shape.

Comment: Currently trying it out, just need my opponent to make a move and see how goes.

Answer (score 4):

There are many options for online chess.

A very simple site I use is itsyourturn.com.

You get email reminders and it just does what you need if you want play chess with a friend.

For more advanced options look at [freechess.org](http://freechess.org). There are several different clients for it.

Answer (score 3):

**[Time for Chess](http://www.timeforchess.com)*?**

It also has a great [iPhone optimised](http://www.timeforchess.com/chess/iphone/play-chess-on-iphone.php) site.

a.k.a. [Red Hot Pawn](http://www.redhotpawn.com) ;)

Comment: +1 I used to use RedHotPawn for correspondence games, before I learned that I'm too impatient for that :)

Comment: Redhotpawn is great!